# Extending a map by specifying key & value types

Tags: java, dictionary

I would like to use a map with specific key & value types across multiple classes in my app. The only way that I know of is to create a class with that specific map as a variable and then pass all the calls through it, i.e:

```
public class SpecificMap {
    public Map<A, B> map;

    public SpecificMap() {
        map = new HashMap<A, B>;
    }
}
```

but this means that I have to use SpecificMap.map.method() each time. I would like to be able to do SpecificMap.method(), which would require to write a method for each required map call, which is cumbersome.

Is there a better way? Maybe something similar to C/C++ typedef?

Comment: You can create some kind of singleton `DataStorage` and name the instance `ds`. I believe it isn't that much more syntax.

Comment: Why can't you just use `Map<A, B>`?

Comment: It's unclear whether you are asking about singleton or inheritance thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try extending e.g. `HashMap<A,B>`, this should do what you need.

Comment: So should I do something like `SpecificMap extends HashMap<A,B> {}` work?

Comment: Yes, that's what I think.